# Devise ajax facebook login

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to get an AJAX facebook login working with devise and followed this post:

http://www.maxgillett.com/post/28504483668/devise-omniauth-facebook-js-sdk-tutorial

It all works except when I sign out and then in again without reloading the page, I get this error:

> ERROR -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure!
>   invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, :  {"error":{"message":"This
>   authorization code has been
>   used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Any idea how to get around this? The tutorial includes extending the token so I'm at a bit of a loss. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version of gem 'omniauth-facebook' it is one of the reason to get that error.